# How do I compare attribute to a lower case value in dynamodb table -> Item -> attribute in query runtime

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I want to search text string in attribute like we do in mysql  LOWER(fieldName) = LIKE% strtolower(search_text)% . I did some r n d but not found any solution.

```
{
    "TableName": "DEV_postTbl",
    "ProjectionExpression": "postId, postType, postStatus",
    "ScanIndexForward": false,
    "Limit": 6,
    "KeyConditionExpression": "postStatus =:postStatusPublished",
    "IndexName": "postStatus-createdOn-index",
    "FilterExpression": " (  contains( postTitle, :searchText)  OR  contains(postDescription, :searchText) OR contains(postLocation.addressLine, :searchText) ) ",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":searchText": "hello",
        ":postStatusPublished": "published"
    }
}
```

This is my code.. but this search only  "hello"  instead of "Hello", "heLLO" like this

Answer (score 2):

> DynamoDB is case sensitive. If your data is case insensitive, one solution is to lower case or upper case the data before storing it in DynamoDB. Then you can get around this by querying for all lower case or all upper case.

Example :

Store `postTitle` with lowerCase items.

When You search just lowerCase the `:searchTex` (str.toLowerCase()) and then query.

Comment: this is user  typed input . if he type  "Home on ReNt"  and have to store as same as he type ..either user can claim that i didn't input this.. another way i found that store same as type and create another attribute with stored LOWER case and use that for search but this will increase write operation of dynamo. @IftekharDani